# Numbered ordering of multiple citations

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I am using `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` to ensure citations are numbered by their appearance in the paper. With multiple citations however, the numbers can be out or order because of the order they appeared somewhere earlier in the paper:

`\cite{paper1, paper2, paper3}` ==> `[5, 3, 10]`

Is there a way to ensure that the numbers appear in order with multiple citations?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This functionality is provided by the [cite package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite).  By default it will also compress lists of citations so [1,2,3] becomes [1-3], however a document stating with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

will produce the effect you wish.  Sorting can be turned off by using the `[nosort]` option.

Incidentally, I notice that there are alternative bibliography styles for IEEE Transactions, called `ieeetrans` which include a variant `ieeetranS` that sorts citations by default.  These styles seem to be newer. May be you should consider using those instead.

Comment: Does not work with biblatex, but may not be necessary for biblatex. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295138/99001

Answer (score 6):

For anyone wondering how this works in biblatex, you need to specify `sortcites=true` option.

E.g. when loading the package:

```
\usepackage[sortcites=true]{biblatex}
```

For more details, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130937/biblatex-numeric-style-multicite-order-of-references) question.