# Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'cite'

Tags: biblatex, errors, packages, citing

I am trying to use biblatex package:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

I get the following error:

> ! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'cite'.

Can someone help me how can I resolve this issue?

I note that I am using our university template for writing a thesis.

Comment: Then your university template probably loads the `cite` package which is incompatible with `biblatex`. Either stop using `biblatex` and use whatever your template uses for the bibliography, or drop the template and use `biblatex`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [cite](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite) package, which is meant to be used with BibTeX and a suitably chosen `\bibliographystyle`, provides tools to manage the typeset format of numeric-style citation call-outs. The [biblatex](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex) package can generate numeric citation call-outs as well, but it uses mechanisms that are incompatible with `cite`.

In short: no need to load `cite` on top of `biblatex`.

Comment: It works, thank you)